# Slow ssh response on macOS

Tags: ssh

I have a macos system (yosemite) running an ssh server, exposing an external port through the router. When I ssh log in from an ubuntu box in a different location, the ssh response is VERY sluggish, as the bash prompt waits several seconds sometimes almost a minute just to return after simple commands like 'ls'.   What can I check to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

Make a test if possible: Login using ssh locally - not from another location. Check the speed. It'll help you understand if the problem is on the mac ssh server or the router - line - other end.